# Retrieve data as custom object Hibernate Criteria

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

The task is to retrieve data from the database for certain list of columns and return as custom already existing class.

I tried to resolve this task with following code:

```
public List<EntityOne> getServiceProviders(EntityTwo EntityTwo) {
        Criteria criteria = createCriteria(EntityOne.class);
        criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("EntityTwo", EntityTwo));
        criteria.createAlias("spid", "two");
        criteria.addOrder(Order.asc("two.entityName"));

        criteria.setProjection(Projections.projectionList()
                .add(Projections.property("entityId"), "entityId")
                .add(Projections.property("publishStatus"), "publishStatus")
                .add(Projections.property("two.entityName"), "two.entityName")
                .add(Projections.property("two.entityId"), "two.entityId")
        );

        return criteria.list();
    }
```

But I receive a list of data that is not grouped in class as I wanted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is not very clear especially where you are attempting to use `Restrictions.eq("EntityTwo", EntityTwo)` as this will not give proper results. Hibernate however provides a means to return `EntityOne` as an Object from the Columns selected using Hibernate `Transformers` class. In your case, you will need to write a custom class with `getter setter` of the columns you are returning. Note that is is important that the variables be named exactly like the alias columns.

Since your example is not clear, let me illustrate with a simple example: Say I need all purchase `OrderAmount` grouped by `OrderDate` and `OrderNumber`

```
 public static List<YourCustomEntity> getAggregateOrders(){
    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    Transaction tx = null;
    List<YourCustomEntity> list =  new ArrayList<YourCustomEntity>();
    try {
        tx = session.beginTransaction();
        Criteria cr = session.createCriteria(PurchaseOrders.class);
        cr.setProjection(Projections.projectionList()
                .add(Projections.sum("orderAmount").as("sumOrderAmount"))
                .add(Projections.groupProperty("orderNumber").as("agOrderNumber"))
                .add(Projections.groupProperty("orderDate").as("agOrderDate")));
        cr.setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(YourCustomEntity.class));
        list = (List<YourCustomEntity>) cr.list();
   }catch (Exception asd) {
        System.out.println(asd.getMessage());
        if (tx != null) {
            tx.rollback();
        }
    } finally {
        session.close();
    }
     return list;
}
```

In this regard, you will need your customEntity to have the three columns returned above. For example:

```
public class YourCustomEntity {

    private double sumOrderAmount;
    private String agOrderNumber;
    private Date agOrderDate;
   //And then the getters and setters
```

**NB:** Notice the naming of the variables is the same as the column aliases.

Answer (score -1):

You should use `Projections.groupProperty(propertyName);`

```
criteria.setProjection(Projections.groupProperty("propertyName"));
```